# Possible to pass resources via IPC?

Tags: resources, ipc

Is it possible to pass resources (file handles, FTP connections, database connections) via IPC (interprocess communication)?

Answer (score 2):

It rather depends on the kind of IPC. In general, IPC is a way to move bytes, so no.

However, some unixes have some capacity to move other objects. For example, Linux can send file descriptors (which i *think* includes sockets) over a [unix-domain socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) (both stream and datagram, i believe) - you have to use the sendmsg routine, passing in a msghdr struct containing an ancillary data pointer pointing to the file descriptors in an array, and performing the necessary incantations (SCM_RIGHTS and so on). The other side will then receive them as working file descriptors in a corresponding msghdr struct, although of course the actual numbers of the file descriptors might be different. You can also send process credentials this way; these are an unforgeable proof of the identity of the process sending them, which is useful for various obscure purposes.

Whether you can move higher-level objects depends on whether they are built out of file descriptors and bytes. However, note that you would have to write code to move these things; you wouldn't expect to be able to send them out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

In windows file and socket handles can be duplicated for another process running on the same system and passed to this process using IPC.

"Database connection" is a term specific to the DB connection mechanism you use. It's possible that some "connections" can be shared, but this will be most likely sharing a connection string.

FTP connections can be shared by duplicating socket handle (if the code is yours) or you can pass the FTP URL to another process.